# Starting the AUTO_INCREMENT with zero

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need some help with MySQL. I have `id` column on my `news` table with AUTO_INCREMENT and as usually it assign `id=1` for the very first news, `id=2` for the second and etc. But I want it to start with `001` instead of `1`, then `002`,`003` and so. How can I do that?

Comment: If you need to display things this way, why not just format the ID after you retrieve it from the database?

Comment: Storing it in the database would seem to be a more efficient approach. That way a format operation is performed only once, as opposed to performing it on each call.

Comment: Exactly, I want to store it in the database.

Comment: The title of your question is a bit misleading: I first thought you were asking how to make the `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequence start from 0 instead of 1.  (Ps. The answer to that question can be found [at the bottom of this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero).)

Answer (score 1):

Use a numeric field and set the field to ZEROFILL. More on how to use ZEROFILL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

Comment: ...and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html#id733596).